# Несовместимость dll, lib и a между компиляторами

Tags: c++, c, dll, lib, extern

Мне бы хотелось разобраться в вопросе (не)совместимости между различными компиляторами **C/C++**. Часто оказывается, что между собой несовместимы даже разные версии одного и того же компилятора. Доступной и детальной информации по этой теме мне найти не удалось.

Вопросы такие:

1) Я знаю, что с совместимостью компиляторов **C++** все очень плохо, потому что язык слишком переусложнен, имеет бесконечное количество тонкостей, исключений из правил и пунктов, которые определяются реализацией. Поэтому я не очень понимаю, зачем используют всякие **export "C"** и **extern "C"**, если двоичные файлы (например, **lib**) практически всегда оказываются совместимы лишь с тем компилятором, которым они сделаны. Так в чем смысл?

2) Если разработка **lib**, **dll** и **a** файлов ведется с использованием языка **C**, то как в этом случае обстоят дела с совместимостью? Все так же плохо, как если бы разработка велась на **C++**? Или нет?

3) Есть ли способы делать двоичные библиотеки максимально совместимыми? Чтобы написанная однажды библиотека **dll** могла быть подключена в самых разных языках без боли и страданий?

Comment: Как минимум `extern "C"` отключает name mangling, что позволяет вызывать отмеченные им функции из кода на С. (Либо, если нацепить его на прототип функции, вызывать сишные функции из С++.) А записи `export "C"` вроде как нет.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите скомпилировать библиотеку на x86 платформе или ARM а потом ее использовать на любой другой?

Comment: Я не говорю про платформы, я говорю про компиляторы/языки. Например, я бы хотел сделать **dll** для **Win x32** и затем подключать ее в других языках/компиляторах на той же системе с тем же типом процессора.

Comment: По пункту №3 советую вам ознакомиться с [рекомендациями по соблюдения ABI от KDE](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B)

Comment: Подумайте сами: если бы DLL на Си были несовместимы между разными компиляторами, программы под ОС можно было бы собирать только одним компилятором (которым собирали DLL этой ОС, содержащие ее системные вызовы). Важно понимать, что необязательно таки писать все на Си, главное экспортировать интерфейс в стиле Си, тогда все будет нормально.

Comment: Я часто сталкиваюсь с библиотеками **.h + .lib + .dll**, которые собирались лишь определенными компиляторами, хотя интерфейс там был экспортирован в C.

Comment: Дело не в том, что `язык слишком переусложнен, имеет бесконечное количество тонкостей, исключений из правил и пунктов, которые определяются реализацией`. Просто стандарт определяет лишь часть, непосредственно видимую программисту. Остальное оставлено на усмотрение разработчиков компилятора. Именно оттуда и растут и невозможность передачи STL-объектов, и несовместимое декорирование имён, и прочие низкоуровневые различия.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несовместимость бинарных модулей (далее, для краткости, просто "модулей"), произведенных разными компиляторами, определяется в основном следующими тремя аспектами:

1. Разные правила декорирования имен экспортируемых символов
2. Разное устройство объектов стандартной библиотеки
3. Разные правила расположения полей структур в памяти

Первый пункт характерен фактически только для С++: в Си существует набор характерных для конкретной аппаратной платформы соглашений о вызове (например, stdcall, fastcall и cdecl для x86), которые довольно четко прописывают правила декорирования имен. Второй пункт относится и к Си и к С++, но в Си не очень много "объектов стандартной библиотеки" - в голову приходит только FILE*, и экспортировать его через границы модулей нет никакого смысла.

Таким образом да, действительно можно сказать, что С++ "хуже" чем Си в плане бинарной совместимости. Это разумеется не значит, что не нужно на нем писать, это лишь значит, что на границе модулей нужно использовать интерфейс в стиле Си (либо использовать стандартизированный объектно-ориентированный интерфейс, например Component Object Model в Windows).

> Есть ли способы делать двоичные библиотеки максимально совместимыми? Чтобы написанная однажды библиотека dll могла быть подключена в самых разных языках без боли и страданий?

Использование DLL на С/С++ в других языках это больше чем вопрос бинарного интерфейса (например, в них может просто не быть концепции заголовочных файлов, указателей и т.п.), но обычно да, библиотека с интерфейсом в стиле Си может быть использована и из других языков с тем или иным количеством дополнительных телодвижений.

Рекомендации для обеспечения максимальной бинарной совместимости:

- Экспортируйте через границы бинарного модуля только простые функции с припиской `extern "C"` (т.е, никаких классов, шаблонов, перегруженных функций, пространств имен и т.п.)
- Передавайте через границы модулей только простые типы, указатели на них и указатели на функции.
- Если все же передаете структуры, сделайте первым членом структуры ее размер. Это позволит, если вы натолкнетесь на различия по выравниванию полей, обнаружить несоответствие в общем размере структуры и хотя бы нормально вернуть ошибку.
- Не передавайте через границы модулей объекты стандартной библиотеки, например указатели FILE*.
- Блоки динамической памяти должны освобождаться всегда в том же модуле, в котором были выделены. Т.е., если библиотека возвращает программе-клиенту указатель на блок памяти, выделенный malloc внутри себя, она должна предоставлять специальную функцию для его освобождения (вызывающую внутри себя free), вместо того, чтобы полагаться на вызов free в программе-клиенте.

Comment: *"Си имеет набор стандартных соглашений о вызове"* - ничего подобного, stdcall, fastcall и cdecl - это все сугубо вендорно-специфичные вещи. *"которые довольно четко прописывают правила декорирования имен"* - соглашения о вызовах вопросы имен не затрагивают. Компиляторы С вольны генерировать код как угодно. Например один может использовать для хранения переменных с автоматическим хранением аппаратный стек, а другой кучу; или в одном имена функций остаются как есть, а в другом вообще отсутствуют.

Comment: Так откуда берется совместимость? Она берется из-за того, что все релевантные операционные системы написаны на С, или, как минимум, предоставляют С интерфейс. Соответственно вендоры следуют совместимости с С интерфейсом, принятым в системе, и получают совместимость с модулями других вендоров на той же системе.

Answer (score 4):

Толстый троллинг по поводу "недостатков" языка С++ продолжается. Ну что же, ринемся на защиту детища Страуструпа.

> 1) Я знаю, что с совместимостью компиляторов C++ все очень плохо,

С совместимостью компиляторов С++ все очень хорошо, гораздо лучше, чем с совместимостью компиляторов с каких-либо других языков. Вплоть до того, что многие языки имеют компилятор только под одну платформу и/или от одного производителя. Конечно, такой подход улучшает совместимость, но ухудшает переносимость и тормозит развитие. При отказе единственного производителя компилятора от поддержки языка 100500 разработчиков повисают в воздухе. Достаточно вспомнить отказ даже такого гиганта как Микрософт от обратной совместимости в языке Visual Basic при переходе от версии VB6 к версии VB.net.

> потому что язык слишком переусложнен,
>   имеет бесконечное количество тонкостей, исключений из правил и
>   пунктов, которые определяются реализацией.

Язык С++ не переусложнен. Просто в языке С++ не включена "защита от дурака". В награду за не включенную "защиту от дурака" пользователи имеют возможность делать то, что им нужно, а не то, что позволяет им язык. Чтобы пользоваться всеми возможностями языка С++ недостаточно выучить синтаксис С++ по первому изданию книжки Страуструпа. Надо еще читать книжки, которые выходят по мере развития языка и в которых обсуждаются как раз те новые возможности, которые некоторых разработчиков приводят к созданию крашащегося кода, а другим разработчикам позволяют съэкономить 100500 часов рабочего времени. Внесение в язык С++ новых возможностей (например шаблонов) порождает взаимодействие этих новых возможностей со старыми возможностями (например с классами). Это взаимодействие может служить как источником ошибок, так и источником новых идей и подходов. Многие достойные люди занимаются исследованиями в этих направлениях и публикуют свои результаты исследований. Изучая эти исследования можно избежать ошибок и воспользоваться новыми подходами. Еще раз повторю что в языке С++ не включена "защита от дурака". И поэтому, чтобы не делать ошибок в языке С++, надо точно понимать, что именно ты делаешь.

> Поэтому я не очень понимаю, зачем используют всякие export "C" и
>   extern "C",

Как тут правильно заметили это отключает манглинг имен.

> если двоичные файлы (например, lib) практически всегда
>   оказываются совместимы лишь с тем компилятором, которым они сделаны.
>   Так в чем смысл?

Под совместимостью различных компиляторов языка С++ имеется ввиду совместимость на уровне исходного текста. Двоичную совместимость объектников, бинарников и библиотек lib никто и никогда не гарантировал. Кстати, это относится и к другим языкам (за исключением языков с виртуальными машинами, но там за это платят тем, что приходится за собой таскать все тупиковые решения и ошибки ради обратной совместимости).

> 2) Если разработка lib, dll и a файлов ведется с использованием языка
>   C, то как в этом случае обстоят дела с совместимостью? Все так же
>   плохо, как если бы разработка велась на C++? Или нет?

Кстати, никто не гарантировал совместимость объектников, бинарников и библиотек lib для языка Си. Трансляторы с языка Си от разных производителей производят объектники разного формата. Ну и что в этом такого?

> 3) Есть ли способы делать двоичные библиотеки максимально
>   совместимыми? Чтобы написанная однажды библиотека dll могла быть
>   подключена в самых разных языках без боли и страданий?

Если в системе Windows dll имеет "pure Си" интерфейс, то ее можно вызвать из многих других языков. Количество боли и страданий при этом зависит от разработчика интерфейса между dll и этим самым языком, из которого dll вызывается. Собственно языки С/С++ к этому не имеют никакого отношения.

UPD1:

> Я не начинал толстый троллинг по поводу недостатков C++, просто это
>   мое мнение, которое основывается на определенном опыте работы с этим
>   языком, в том числе в международных группах разработчиков. – Максим 2
>   минуты назад

Уважаемый Максим, количество использующих язык С++ разработчиков в мире (в том числе в международных группах разработчиков) убедительно показывает, что язык C++ вполне жизнеспособен. Если бы это было не так, то от языка С++ давно бы отказались, как отказались в свое время от 100500 других языков.

UPD2:

> С тем, что С++ жизнеспособен, никто не спорит. Но все-таки в нем
>   действительно много разных тонкостей и хитростей. – HolyBlackCat 10
>   секунд назад

Как я уже сказал, все эти "тонкости и хитрости" это следствие того, что новые возможности добавляются в язык и на уровне транслятора отсутствуют семантические и синтаксические ограничения на использование этих новых возможностей. Также  на уровне транслятора отсутствуют семантические и синтаксические ограничения на взаимодействие новых возможностей со старыми возможностями. Это, с одной стороны, добавляет мощи. А с другой стороны, ограничения на использование новых средств должны храниться в голове программиста, а не прошиваются в синтаксисе языка.

В любом случае, все, кому С++ кажется слишком сложным/непонятным/переусложненным/плохо совместимым может пользоваться любыми другими языками вместо того, чтобы перечислять мнимые недостатки С++. Потому что все эти якобы недостатки С++ это вовсе не недостатки, а это такой подход при котором транслятор не мешает Вам выстрелить себе в ногу, но зато дает возможность выстрелить на 100500 километров при правильном использовании. На свете есть 100500 трансляторов, которые мешают программисту выстрелить себе в ногу, но зато и ограничивают возможности.

UPD3:

Извините за частое употребление идиомы 100500, но уж очень она тут подходит. :-)

Comment: Я не начинал *толстый троллинг* по поводу недостатков **C++**, просто это мое мнение, которое основывается на определенном опыте работы с этим языком, в том числе в международных группах разработчиков.

Comment: С тем, что С++ жизнеспособен, никто не спорит. Мне как язык он очень нравится. Но все-таки в нем действительно много разных тонкостей и хитростей. Возможно слишком много.